# где учить django 2

Tags: python-3.x, django

кто-нибудь может порекомендовать курс по django 2

на русском языке и чтобы у автора была Windows

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Learn/Server-side/Django

Answer (score 1):

Предлагаю Вашему вниманию бесплатный видео-курс от технотрека Mail.ru Group: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLrCZzMib1e9pg7ZLIOhmGSlmkMf8yEOLZ

Курс на русском.
Лекции читают разработчики из Mail.Ru.
В нём охвачено большинство основных возможностей Django, в том числе и некоторые продвинутые методики.

---

Также могу порекомендовать русский перевод текстового курса от Django Girls:
https://tutorial.djangogirls.org/ru/

Затронуты в основном базовые вещи, но уделено внимание загрузке сайта на бесплатный хостинг.

***P. S.:***
Курсов, где у автора Windows, Вы почти не найдёте, но это не проблема. Все команды, которые исполняют в курсах, прекрасно работают и на Windows, не понимаю почему это так принципиально.

Comment: это очень старые видео там не используется джанго  2

Comment: @MP3 Скорее всего, Вы правы. Но отличие версий совсем незначительно для базовых вещей, поэтому код из курса будет работать в большинстве случаев и без изменений как таковых.