# Как получить текущего user'а в views.py - django?

Tags: python, django

Нужно чтобы любой зарегистрировавшийся пользователь мог создать пост. Поля модели поста = title, descr, **current_user**(здесь должен храниться объект пользователя создавшего пост, это и не получается!).

views.py

```
def view_foo(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        if request.method == 'GET':
            form = CreatePost()
            return render(request, 'testapp/create.html', {'form': form})

        if request.method == 'POST':
            form = CreatePost(request.POST)
            post = form.save(commit=False)

            post.current_user = request.user ## Здесь ошибка, не знаю как 
                                               ## записать текущего юзера в current_user 

           post.save()

           return redirect('index')
    else:
       return HttpResponse('No authenticated')
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

# Create your models here.
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)


class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=59, verbose_name='Название')
    descr = models.TextField(max_length=59, db_index=True, verbose_name='Описание')
    current_user = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы пытаетесь привязать пользователя (`User`), хотя должны привязывать его профайл (`UserProfile`).

***P. S.:***
В целом, это не очень хорошее архитектурное решение, поэтому я советую Вам связать модель поста непосредственно с моделью пользователя.

***Пример:***

```py
...
class Post(models.Model):
    ...
    current_user = models.ForeignKey(User, ...)
```

После этого представление должно работать без ошибок.

Comment: Если так исправить, то всё работает, но если я хочу сохранить дополнительную информацию о User'е, то мне обязательно создавать модель UserProfile. И поэтому поле current_user в модели Post, должно ссылаться на UserProfile. Если я, конечно, всё правильно понимаю.
Нужно другое решение

Comment: @OriginalHater Я не согласен с Вами. Вы создаёте дополнительную информация о посте, а не о пользователе. Тут вполне уместно использовать связь с моделью пользователя напрямую. Модель `UserProfile` создана только для расширения информации о модели `User`. Я считаю, что у неё не должно быть других связей.

Comment: @OriginalHater Кстати, такой подход исключает сразу множество ошибок. Я думаю, что Вы уже убедились в этом, когда пробовали ответ pythoner. Вам приходится заботиться о модели `UserProfile` без контекста модели `User`, чего, по моему мнению, не должно происходить. В конце концов, это просто лишняя прослойка, которая ничего полезного не даёт. А вот вред, в виде лишней связи и запутанности отношений, присутствует :)

Comment: А как мне вывести все посты созданные пользователем, без связи `UserProfile` с `Post`?))

Comment: @OriginalHater `Post.objects.filter(current_user=request.user)`. Как видите, довольно удобно. Мы хотим вывести посты и обращаемся напрямую к модели `Post`.

Comment: У меня есть список пользователей, и мне нужно при клике на одного из них вывести все посты, которые он создал.

Comment: @OriginalHater Типичная задача. Узнайте его id, получите объект этого пользователя, получите все его записи. Вот пример: `user = User.objects.get(id=user_id); posts_list = Post.objects.filter(current_user=user)`

Comment: Решив эту задачу, понял на сколько она элементарная. Всё было очень просто. Спасибо вам большое, за помощь!! Не могли бы ещё порекомендовать литературы или других ресурсов для изучения django?

Comment: @OriginalHater Лучший источник знаний после изучения основ - документация. Радует, что она очень подробная и с примерами. Также помогают на SO (как, например, я Вам <3) Изучить основы можно по моим рекомендация из [недавнего ответа](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/997139/339283). _P. S.: Это лишь те методы и источники, по которым я лично изучал Django, руководствуйтесь собственным видением ситуации._

Answer (score 1):

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required


@login_required
def view_foo(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        form = CreatePost()
        return render(request, 'testapp/create.html', {'form': form})

    elif request.method == 'POST':
        form = CreatePost(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            post = form.save(commit=False)
            post.current_user = UserProfile.objects.get(user=request.user)
            post.save()
            return redirect('index')
```

Comment: Изменив код как вы показали получаю такую ошибку:
 _DoesNotExist at /create/_
_UserProfile matching query does not exist._

Comment: Я так понимаю, проблема в том, что созданных мною юзеров нет в таблице UserProfile. Я добавил в регистрационную вьюшку эту строку: `UserProfile.objects.create(user=user)` и всё заработало, но только с заново созданными юзерами. А как быть со старыми, которые были созданы до добавление этой строки. И вообще правильно ли это при регистрации пользователя заносить его в таблицу UserProfile?

Comment: @OriginalHater Да. Удобно это делать через сигналы. Также, могу посоветовать Вам манипулировать профайлом пользователя через основную модель. Я подробно описал эти темы в [одном из своих ответов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/992552/339283)

Comment: @OriginalHater используйте сигналы, как Вам посоветовали выше.